# "На этот раз" — нужны ли запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Какое **на этот раз** ты придумал ему наказание?*

Comment: Нормальный вопрос, только его надо переформулировать, например: Нужны ли запятые в этом предложении? Или конкретнее: Нужно ли обособлять сочетание "на этот раз"?

Answer (score 1):

**Какое на этот раз  //  ты придумал ему наказание?**

Это простое предложение, в котором нет запятых: предложное сочетание ***на этот раз*** не обособляется, так как входит в основную структуру предложения по схеме тема ― рема, предмет ― сообщение о предмете.

Небольшая пауза обозначает конец первой интонационной фразы ***какое на этот раз...*** , запятая в таких случаях не ставится.

Падежная форма ***на этот раз*** может стоять в начале обособленного оборота, например: **Придумай ему другое наказание, на этот раз особенное.**

Answer (score 1):

Фразеологический словарь русского литературного языка:

**[На сей (этот) раз](https://phraseology.academic.ru/10342/%D0%9D%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9_%28%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%29_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7)**
Теперь, в это время.
*Оказалось, что **на этот раз** весь губернский люд словно сговорился и собрался ранее обыкновенного* (Салтыков-Щедрин. Помпадуры и помпадурши).

**На этот раз** — наречное выражение (обстоятельство времени), имеет значение *в данном случае, сейчас*; в этом предложении обособления (запятых) не требует.

*Но ты сама выбирала себе подарки. И на этот раз ты выбрала пластмассового носорога, достаточно пупырчатого и достаточно зеленого, чтобы смахивать на рептилию*.
В. Панюшкин. Отцы